# New line in CSV file

Tags: c#, csv

In below code I want to get Test1 value in new line of CSV file for each cycle of loop. How could I do this -

```
for (int j = 0; j < 10000; j++)
{ 
             if (NPVAmount > 0)  // Positive amount 
            {
                Positivetemp = NPVAmount + Positivetemp;
                Temp = Convert.ToString(Positivetemp)+ ","+ j +","+ UniqueCurrencyHolder+",";
                Test1 =Test1 + Temp;

             }
}
```

Comment: Use `System.Environment.NewLine` to add new lines. However, why do the CSV hard work yourself, when open source like FileHelpers and CSVHelper exist?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use `Environment.NewLine`

```
Test1 =Test1 + Environment.NewLine;
```

Answer (score 2):

Declare a list of string

```
List<string> csvLines = new List<string>();
```

Then in the loop add `Test1` to the csvLines.

```
csvLines.Add(Test1);
```

Then write all of the Test1's to a file once the loop has finished.

```
File.WriteAllLines("Path", csvLines);
```

This should achieve what you want I think going by what you have given.